# Make elements automatically fit width of parent w/o tables/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-tables

Is it possible to create a div containing multiple boxes that automatically fit to the size of the parent (distributed evenly) without the use of a table or Javascript? I realize that it is possible with `table-layout:fixed;` but I have tried to animate that and it did not seem to work very well. The following picture is an example of what I mean:

[image: A gif showing autosizing boxes]

I am trying to increase the width of one box inside the div which will then case the rest of the boxes to automatically size so all of the boxes fit into the div evenly. I need it to be animated, not just instant in which case I would just use a table. I have also experimented with it using Javascript, animating it with a  `-webkit-transition` but this did not turn out to animate very well. Instead of expanding/decreasing in size, the box seemed to start out it's width at 0px then stretch to the size given to it. (this was using a table with `table-layout:fixed`. Is there a pure CSS/HTML way to do this, or does it **require** the use of Javascript and/or a table?

Comment: +1 for the very illustrative question, + its actually a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a fixed number of children it’s possible without tables (although you need table displays), here is the CSS I used:

```
.parent{width:400px;height:100px;display:table}

.parent div{display:table-cell;border:1px solid #000;
    -webkit-transition:width 1s;width:20%}

.parent:hover div{width:10%}
.parent div:hover{width:60%}
```

You need to manually calculate the percents for the best results in the animation. Demo:

http://jsbin.com/ubucod/1

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, a very simple and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the boxes to animate on a click/touch then you'll need Javascript.

If you want the boxes to animate only on rollover then you can apply css to the parent element to set all boxes to the same percent by default and change them on rollover.

This solution only works for a fixed number of boxes though.

```
    #Container .box{
        width: 20%;
        transition: width 0.2s;            
    }
    #Container:hover .box{
        width: 10%;
    }
    .box:hover{
        width: 60%;
    }
```

I haven't tested it but it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="pushercolumn"></div>
<div class="pushedcolumn">
    <div class="unit"></div>
    <div class="unit"></div>
    <div class="unit"></div>
    <div class="unit"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pushercolumn {
    float: left; 
    width: 30%; /*or whichever you want*/
}

.pushedcolumn {
    overflow: hidden; /* guarantees the .pushedcolumn is pushed horizontally by the floats */
    font-size: 0; /* removes white-space. choose your preferred method*/
}

.unit {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%; /* assuming there are 4 boxes in the right column. this is the only variable you have to update based on the circumstances */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xYAdR/